# Search results getting lost on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, http, razor

I am new to this MVC Architecture so please execuse for basic or amature questions.

I need to implement a search functionality. I created an action in Home Controller `SearchFNW(searchstring)`. In this method I got a list of ViewModels with searched data.

I am passing this list to Index.cshtml and trying to display results in a table.

I am able to get the View Model's List data to View.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<First_Niagara_Works.ViewModels.AccountViewModel>
@{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
    {   
       if (Model != null)
       {
           // code to populate table using model
       } 
    }
}
```

**Homecontroller.cs**

```
public ActionResult SearchFNW(string FNWtodo, string SearchInput)
{
    // all code to load viewmodels to list

    return View(@"~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", lstAccountVM);
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Problem:** After execution of this code it redirects to Layout.cshtml and from there it calls Index action again .. and started all over again with @Html.beginform(). so not able to see table data with searched results..

Comment: So where users could submit there search queries? In index page and inside of the `form`?

Comment: You are **not** passing the list to the the `Index()` method. The `Index()` method does not have a parameter for the list, and even if it did, it would not work (you cant pass a collection of complex objects to an `ActionResult`. Very hard to understand what you really want to do since your code does not match the text in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string FNWtodo, string SearchInput)
{
     // all code to load viewmodels to list

    return View(lstAccountVM);
}


public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Your form `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))` submits a `POST` back to the `Index` Action in the controller. You just need to use the Index action that captures the `[HttpPost]` and it will return the `Index` view but with your populated model.